# Why would somebody want to stop the four elements?

Tags: magic, environment, earth, water, fire

I'm writing a story about the four elements that are in four people. One controls water, one controls fire, and so on for air and earth. Why would the antagonist want to get rid of the four people/element controllers

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Please review these links and help us by improving your question.

Comment: The [Avatar](http://www.nick.com/avatar-the-last-airbender/episodes/) series is a good start

Comment: Also see captian planet and the planeteers